How to build many React apps from the same config files?
So I have a React app, and for my purposes I want to make various React apps but they need to share the same configs - the same modules, the same config files (such as tailwind.config.cjs). How can I setup my environment so it becomes possible?
I will actually manually move each build to other folders on a Django app. I really only need React to build some complex UI that would be a pain with Vanilla JS.
I don't really feel like having to copy all my React app and then having a different stance of it with the same configs for each page I want to build, even though this would work, my codebase would grow too much and if I had to change a config (like a theme for tailwind for example) I would need to change it on every project.
So basically I want a React setup that imports all those configs from a parent directory, for example.

Why don't copy the app to a new folder, strip everything except the config etc, add it to github as a scaffold project, and then just clone as and when you need to.

@Andy I may want to change the configs after I have many apps. Also I'd rather have a local setup.

If I got your question correct I think you are trying to find a way how to create new React application with your custom file structure. Where you will have your tailwind configs and other stuffs.
So for that you can create a template structured application and then while creating new project you can pass --template flag with mentioning your own created template.
See more detailed instruction here - https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-vite
Also this is possible with basic create-react-app - https://create-react-app.dev/docs/custom-templates/. But I think they have some differences.
